# indice fuera de rango en una iteracion Python

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy creando una funcion con dos variables. Una variable es un numero en forma de string, y la otra es una lista de numeros. Lo que la funcion debe devolverme es QUE DIGITOS DEL NUMERO NO ESTAN CONTENIDOS EN LA LISTA. Aqui les dejo el codigo que cree:

```
def not_accepted_digits(String, digit_list):
    string_list = [str(item) for item in digit_list]
    not_accepted_digits = []
    for i in range(len(String)):
        if String[i] not in string_list:
            not_accepted_digits.append(String[i])
    return not_accepted_digits
```

Cuando introduzco los valores de ambas variables por ejemplo:

```
not_accepted_digits('12345', [1, 2, 3])
['4', '5']
```

Me sale que los digitos_string '4' y '5' no estan contenidos en la lista. Bien. Pero cual es el 'defecto' de esta funcion. Es el siguiente, veamos otro ejemplo:

```
not_accepted_digits('1234445', [1, 2, 3])
['4', '4', '4', '5']
```

el defecto es que si el string tiene digitos repetidos la funcion devuelve los digitos repetidos tambien. Y yo lo que deseo que la funcion SIMPLEMENTE ME DEVUELVE QUE DIGITOS NO ESTAN CONTENIDOS EN LA LISTA, es decir que retorne solamente para el caso anterior un '4' y un '5', no que me de los tres 4. Me explico?
Entonces para resolver este problema yo agregue lo siguiente a la funcion:

```
def not_accepted_digits(String, digit_list):
    string_list = [str(item) for item in digit_list]
    not_accepted_digits = []
    for i in range(len(String)):
        if String[i] not in string_list:
            not_accepted_digits.append(String[i])
    for g in range(0, len(not_accepted_digits) - 1):
        if not_accepted_digits[g] == not_accepted_digits[g + 1]:
            not_accepted_digits.remove(not_accepted_digits[g])
    return not_accepted_digits
```

Cuando pruebo esta funcion Python me responde diciendome

list index out of range

no entiendo porque list index esta fuera de rango.

Para concluir, yo pido dos cosas: 1) que me expliquen cual es el error que estoy cometiendo en mi ultima funcion y 2) obtener una funcion que me devuelva un '4' y '5', para el caso de las siguientes dos variables String = '1234445' y List_num = [1, 2, 3]

muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Modificar una lista mientras estas iterando sobre ella es vivir en pecado y mereces todo lo malo que te pase

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está en que al remover valores de la lista usando `not_accepted_digits.remove()` ya la lista no tiene el mismo tamaño que al inicio, y por tanto, se va de rango y lanza una excepción.

La solución es muy simple, solo checa antes de agregar el nuevo dígito si el valor ya está en la lista. Si ya está en la lista, simplemente no lo agregas. Quedaría así:

```
def not_accepted_digits(String, digit_list):
    string_list = [str(item) for item in digit_list]
    not_accepted_digits = []
    for i in range(len(String)):
        if String[i] not in string_list  and String[i] not in not_accepted_digits:
            not_accepted_digits.append(String[i])      
    return not_accepted_digits
```

Comment: Moraleja: Nunca elimines un elemento mientras iteras sobre una lista.